# learning graphics & art making using Mathematica

Tags: graphics

Is there a text book devoted to students who would like to make mathematical art using Mathematica?

I have searched Google for the search term *make mathematical art using Mathematica* and no text books were returned.

Comment: This tag might be a start: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generative-art

Comment: Relevant: https://wolfr.am/arts

Answer (score 3):

The one book that comes to mind is [The Mathematica GuideBook for Graphics](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387950105). It has some years on its back but still, it provides you with the knowledge how to turn math into images.

[image]

Comment: Good book, but when it was written (with Mathematica 5.x) before `Dynamic` and `Manipulate` where created.

Comment: I consider creating the graphics and doing stunts with polygons far more complicated than varying a variable with `Manipulate`. If you learnt Micheal Trott's programming style, it's really a piece of cake to make it dynamic.